# Grid inside Expander Content doesnt align left

Tags: wpf, expander

Can anyone help me solve my issue? When this view load, the expander does expand but inside the content, the grid doesnt align left. I've tried everything possible I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Expander Background="White" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Header="Test" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
        <Expander.Content>
            <Label Background="Orange" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <Grid FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Width="816" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkTest" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="15,0,0,0" Content="Test"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtBlah" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Blah" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        <CheckBox Name="chkTest2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="15,0,0,0" Content="Test2"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtBlahBlah" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="BlahBlah" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Name="txtBlockTest3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="Test3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtTest4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="Test4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Name="txtBlockTest5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6"  Text="Test5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbTest6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
            </Label>
        </Expander.Content>
    </Expander>
```

Comment: Is changing the flowdirection part of the trying everything possible, or do you actually need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `FlowDirection="LeftToRight"` from the `Grid` to the `Label` should do the job.

```
<Label FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Background="Orange" Margin="5">
    <Grid Width="816" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much. I was struggling with this for the past hour or so.